# Wordpress IF statement not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement

I have an IF statement stating the following...

```
                 <?php

                    if (empty($data['footer_text'])) {

                        echo'<p>&copy;&nbsp;';
                            print(Date("Y"));
                        echo'<span class="sep"> | </span><a href="';
                            echo get_settings('home');
                        echo'" title="';
                            bloginfo( 'name' );
                        echo'" rel="home">';
                            bloginfo( 'name' );
                        echo'</a></p>';
                    }

                    else{
                        echo'<p>';
                            global $data; 
                        echo $data['footer_text']; 
                        echo'</p>';
                    }

                ?>
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I call it like this.

```
       <p><?php global $data; echo $data['footer_text']; ?>;</p>
```

It displays my text correctly. But when I use the IF statement it always defaults to the showing the site name even when I know it's displaying the text correctly.

Is my syntax screwed up? I can't figure out why it thinks nothing is there but still shows up when I display in a p tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't declare $data to be global until you're INSIDE the if(), meaning that $data is undefined at the point you're doing the

```
if (empty($data[...])) {
```

you probably want

```
global $data;
if (empty($data[...])) {
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick! - I will mark yours as answered once StackOverflow allows for it. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug the variable `$data['footer_text']`:

```
<?php var_dump($data['footer_text']); ?>
```

just before IF statement. Remember, when `empty()` returns true.

Comment: $data is undefined I needed to call it before the if statement. Thank you so much for the help!